# Animation-Delay não funciona corretamente dentro do Kayframe CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

Eu quero que meu texto apareça depois de 6 segundos, ja tentei de tudo mas ele aparece na tela desde o inicio da execução, não entendo o por que o animation-delay não funciona.
Como resolvo?

```css
#i1 {
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 420px;
    left: 400px;
    font-size: 100px;
    animation: i1 6s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    

}


@keyframes i1{

    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 100%;}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>txt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inicio.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="i1">texto</h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, o `opacity` inicial é 1 (já que não foidefinido um valor diferente), e leva 3s para iniciar a animação que vai de 0 a 1, se você quer que antes da animação começar, fique tranparente, defina a opacidade inicial como 0

```css
#i1 {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: i1;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes i1{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="i1">Texto</h1>
```